# crop an image into several rectangles

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to automatically process grayscale images like this[image] and crop them into rectangular tiles. I used contour() [image]to find the edges but how can I crop the image using the result of contour ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is already double grayscale (otherwise use `im2double` or `rgb2gray`), you can create a simple binary mask using:

```
IM %your image
M=IM>.5
```

Which means the mask contains a `true` for all values larger than .5. To select these pixels, use:

```
IM(M)
```

To select the opposite set, use:

```
IM(~M)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic algorithm would go somewhat like this:

```
1) recognize all horizontal lines
2) recognize all vertical lines
3) create a grid using all the lines from (1) and (2) - this will create more rectangles than you ultimately want, but each rectangle will be a single color
4) combine rectangles that are the same color and adjacent in one direction
5) combine the results of (4) in the other direction, possibly splitting some of the earlier combinations to come up with more a more optimal solution (e.g. in your example the two white rectangles in the first row and the three in the second row could be combined into a group of 2x2 rectangles by splitting the three into 1+2, giving you a 2x2 and a 1x1 rectangle, rather than a 2x1 and a 3x1).
```